# General: 2456 is not a valid variable

Tags: wolfram-cloud, wolfram-alpha-queries

... is not a valid variable i dont know whats happend

[image]

Comment: If you run this code twice then `a` has a value and can't be used as variable in `D`. Start with ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2082114).

Comment: The definitions of `d1`, `d2`, and `d3` can be simplified to either `{d1, d2, d3} = D[a^2*b*(1+b)/(c^(1/3)), {{a, b, c}}] // Simplify` or `{d1, d2, d3} = Grad[a^2*b*(1+b)/(c^(1/3)), {a, b, c}]  // Simplify` and you have several unnecessary uses of `N`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

Start your code with this statement:

```
Clear[a,b,c,aa,bb,cc];
```

Then enter your code until the definitions of d1, d2 and d3. Now define these variables a bit differently. For example, for d1 it is:

```
d1 = D[(a^2*b*(1 + b) c^(-1/3)), a] /. {a -> 2456, b->0.00078, c->0.008};
```

and also d2,d3 and df define analogously. In this case, the values 2456, 0.00078, and 0.008 will be once inserted into the final expression for d1, but a, b and c, will not be assigned to those values, but will, instead, stay variables.

Have fun!